# Mysql array data not display table

Tags: php, html, mysql, zend-framework

I have use MySQL Table get values on table ,that values used another table .i got array values

first table query:

```
    $ordersdetail = "SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE `Order_ID`='".$orderid ."'";
$customerorder = mysql_query($ordersdetail );
                   $i=0;
             while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($customerorder ))
             {
                $orderproduct= $rows['Order_product_ID'];
                $orderids= $rows['Order_ID'];
                $productId[$i] = $rows['Product_ID'];
                $sizeId[$i] = $rows['Size_ID'];

                 $colorId[$i] = $rows['Color_ID'];
                  $quantiy = $rows['Order_Quantity'][$i];

                  $price = $rows['Unit_Price'][$i];
                  $subTotal = $rows['Sub_Total'];
                  $customerccode = $rows['Record_Status'];
                  $customerphone = $rows['Created_Time'];
                  $i++;
                }
```

table column productid array values get used another table:

given:

```
       for($i=0;$i<count($productId);$i++)  
             { 
        $product = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `Product_ID`='".$productId[$i]."'";
$products = mysql_query($product);

             while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($products))         
               { 
                   $productnames = $rows['Product_Name'];


               }

                  }  

color id used :




     for($i=0;$i<count($colorId);$i++) 
                { 
       $color = "SELECT * FROM `color` WHERE `Color_ID`='".$colorId[$i] ."'";
$cname = mysql_query($color);

             while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($cname))         
               { 
                   $colorname = $rows['Color_Name'];
               }
                  }
```

same way used the values table

my questions that values displayed table continuely

```
         table structure  



        $message .= "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
          <thead>
         <tr style='background: #eee;'>
          <th><strong>Quantity</strong> </th>
          <th><strong>ProductName</strong> </th>
         <th><strong>Size</strong> </th>
           <th><strong>Style</strong> </th>
          <th><strong>Price</strong> </th>
          <th><strong>Total</strong> </th>

            </tr>
                 ";
          for($i=0;$i<count($productId);$i++)  
             { 
                      $message .=" <tr style='color: #c40000;'>
                      <th>" .$quantiy. "</th>
                     <th>" .$productnames. "</th>
                         <th>" .$sizename. "</th>
                            <th>" .$colorname. "</th>
                               <th>" . $price. "</th>
                                   <th>" . $subTotal. "</th>  
                                                        </tr>";
                           }
```

this format is correct more values not displayed only first values display multiple time

Comment: Your loop just prints the same thing everytime, you would need to tell it to print something different if you want something different, Really you should put your product list into an array then loop the array, at the moment, the above is just strings. eg $quantity, nothing changes it to the $quantity of product 2

Comment: Please, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because you probably have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Using `mysql_query` is also a bad idea because it's being removed in future versions of PHP. PDO is a modern alternative that's easier to use correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard one to answer because there there is a lot of issues going on....

First off....unless this is a private/internal application, you cant place variables directly into your query...look into a proper database class, I can recommend : http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

Secondly, your are mixing your php code and html too much...I'm not going to go into this too much but in general you want to keep this stuff seperate...research MVC programming patterns.

Now to answer your question...The reason you are seeing the same data repeat is because you you are using only one variable that is getting overwritten each time...ie. $quantiy (which is spelled wrong fyi)...so to hack your approach, assign it to an array and then use an $i counter on it like you are doing with $productID

A better approach would be to do this stuff in the loop and avoid assign the vars in the first place...I'm assuming you have assign stuff to the message var...if you can skip that and echo it out directly that would probably be better.

```
$ordersdetail = "SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE `Order_ID`='".$orderid ."'";
$customerorder = mysql_query($ordersdetail );
$i=0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($customerorder ))
    $product = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `Product_ID`='".$row[$i]."'";
    $products = mysql_query($product);
    $color = "SELECT * FROM `color` WHERE `Color_ID`='".$colorId[$i] ."'";
    $cname = mysql_query($color);


   Now you would create your table from the $rows data directly and when you goto the      color/size stuff you could look through in there.

}
```

Now I'm not 100% sure it will work for you but you could probably do something similar to above with a single query using JOINS

```
SELECT * FROM `order_item` LEFT JOIN product ON order_item.productID = product.productID LEFT JOIN color ON order_item.colorID = color.colorID WHERE order_item.`Order_ID`='".$orderid ."'
```

Please pardon the syntax/naming conventions...the above command will not run properly on your system, it is only meant to give you an idea on what to do.

Comment: I would question "unless this is a private/internal application, you cant place variables directly into your query". Whilst you certainly shouldn't use user input directly in a query without some form of sanitation, you most certainly can use variables in queries, if you should is another matter.